# Android: onBackPress the fragment reloads

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have a navigation activity with 10 fragments consisting of `WebView`.

Now when I enter/transits from "A" fragment to "B" and later `onBackPress` it transits back to "A" but it reloads again.

I wanted to come back to the same position where "A" was left.

Comment: If this is related to the question you asked earlier today, it is because you are removing the fragment from the backstack. Either way, you should post your code so we can get a better idea of what you are doing.

Comment: in onpause() method save your position of movie or somthing else and in onresume set again variable and position for more detail read this doc
https://www.journaldev.com/9266/android-fragment-lifecycle

Comment: maybe post your code it will help us to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it properly, use `ViewModel`, here's a [guide](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e).

If that is too complicated, you can imitate a ViewModel by saving data somewhere in your activity during a fragments `onPause()`. For example:

```
boolean alreadyLoaded = true;
boolean btn1Shown = true;
String editText1Text = editText1.getText().toString;
```

And add to your `onCreateView()`

```
if (alreadyLoaded) {
  if (btn1Shown)
     btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  editText1.setText(editText1Text);
```

This will probably require some interface, or public activity methods, and thats why ViewModel exists so that you don't have to do those things.